# Ошибка с возвратам на фрагмент с google maps

Tags: android, google-maps-api, android-fragment, fragment-manager

У меня 2 фрагмента.

1 - Фрагмент с google картами.
2 - Обычный фрагмент.

Я делаю перелистывание с первого фрагмента на второй.
Перелистывание идет, но вернуться назад я не могу, возвращает ошибку:

> Exception in MessageQueue callback: handleReceiveCallback
>   android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #15: Binary XML
>   file line #15: Error inflating class fragment

**Как реализовываю перелистывание:**

```
fragmentmanager = getActivity().getSupportFragmentManager();
fragmenttransaction = fragmentmanager.beginTransaction();
                    fragmenttransaction.setCustomAnimations(R.anim.slide_left_to_right, R.anim.slide_right_to_left);
                    if (fragmentmanager.findFragmentByTag(fragment_new_order_sub_data.TAG) == null) {
                        fragmenttransaction.replace(R.id.layout_order, fragment_new_order_sub_data, fragment_new_order_sub_data.TAG);
                        fragmenttransaction.addToBackStack("");
                    }
fragmenttransaction.commit();
```

**Вот первый фрагмент:**

```
@Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_new_order_map, container, false);
        return v;
    }

    @Override
    public void onActivityCreated(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);
    }

    private void setUpMapIfNeeded() {
        mapFragment = ((SupportMapFragment) getChildFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.map));
        mapFragment.getMapAsync(new OnMapReadyCallback() {
            @Override
            public void onMapReady(GoogleMap googleMap) {
                if (googleMap != null) {
                }
            }
        });

    }

    @Override
    public void onDetach() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onDetach();
        try {
            Field childFragmentManager = Fragment.class
                    .getDeclaredField("mChildFragmentManager");
            childFragmentManager.setAccessible(true);
            childFragmentManager.set(this, null);

        } catch (NoSuchFieldException e) {
            throw new RuntimeException(e);
        } catch (IllegalAccessException e) {
            throw new RuntimeException(e);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onResume() {
        super.onResume();
        setUpMapIfNeeded();
    }


    @Override
    public void onPause() {
        super.onPause();
        mapFragment.onPause();
    }

    @Override
    public void onDestroy() {
        super.onDestroy();
        mapFragment.onDestroy();
    }

    @Override
    public void onLowMemory() {
        super.onLowMemory();
        mapFragment.onLowMemory();
    }

    @Override
    public void onDestroyView()
    {
        super.onDestroyView();       
    }
```

На просторах интернета вычитал следующее решение, что надо добавить во фрагмент следующее:

```
 @Override
    public void onDestroyView()
    {
        super.onDestroyView();
        try {
            Fragment fragment = (getChildFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.map));
            fragmentmanager = getActivity().getSupportFragmentManager();
            fragmenttransaction = fragmentmanager.beginTransaction();
            fragmenttransaction.remove(fragment);
            fragmenttransaction.commit();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
```

Ок! Все вроде бы работает! Перелистывание идет и при нажатие на кнопку - Назад, возвращается без ошибок!

**НО!**

Если попробовать свернуть приложение, появляется ошибка:

> FATAL EXCEPTION: main
>   java.lang.IllegalStateException: Failure saving state: active
>   SupportMapFragment{4dee6bf} has cleared index: -1

Вот как решить ее я не совсем понимаю! Не понятно, почему он говорит что стек ушел в -1, когда удаляю фрагмент обычным методом remove через менеджер фрагментов.

Кто сталкивался с похожей ситуацией?

Answer (score 2):

Решил так:

Убрал удаление фрагмента из `onDestroyView` и добавил данный код в `onCreateView`:

```
if (rootView != null) {
    ViewGroup parent = (ViewGroup) rootView.getParent();
    if (parent != null)
        parent.removeView(rootView);
}
try {
    rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_new_order_map, container, false);
} catch (InflateException e) {
    /* map is already there, just return view as it is */
}
```